# Deallocate memory of reducer Iterable input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, garbage-collection, heap-memory, iterable

I am facing a GC overhead problem because the reducer input is huge. There is no way for me to filter out any of this input data as all entries in the Iterable argument are of use. I tried increasing the heap size on the EMR cluster where I am running this job, but even that didn't help.

Basically what my reducer does is that it takes a list of strings and converts them into a list of objects A. These objects are then combined to form a bigger object B. The solution that I could think of was, that I can dump the entire Iterable input onto disk and free the Iterable object completely. Then from disk read the dumped string one at a time and keep building the larger object B, by intermediately building an object A and then release A before fetching the next string from the disk. This way, I would keep nearly only half of data on the heap than before. But, I think I am unable to free the Iterable input as I am still getting GC overhead.

The way I tried to do this is as follows:

```
public void reduce(final Text key, Iterable<MapWritable> inputValues,
                   final Context context)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriterWithEncoding(this.fileName, this.encoding));
    for (Iterator<MapWritable> iterator = inputValues.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        MapWritable mapWritable = iterator.next();
        // ----
        // Put string contained in mapWritable into a file on disk
        // ----
    }
    bw.close();

    // Release the input Iterable instance
    inputValues = null;  //This doesn't seem to work :'(

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(this.fileName), this.encoding));
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;)
    {
        // ----
        // Then read from the file saved in disk one line at a time
        // and process it to build the object B
        // ----
    }
    br.close();
}
```

**My question is, is there a way to deallocate the memory of the Iterable input of reducer, from within the reducer method?**

Comment: Hadoop doesn't put the reduce values in memory that are accessed via the Iterable. To me it looks like your code is basically duplicating the functionally the reduce is already giving you, ie a scalable way to access a potentially very large list.

Comment: Thanks @Binary Nerd. I wasn't aware that Iterable itself is a stream. Given that, there is not need to do what I was trying to do. The GC overhead is caused by an individual data instance being too large.